# Print a php variable on a white background, then stop execution

Tags: php

Say I have a simple function like this:

```
function doSomething(){
    $val = "some text";
    //function to print $val on a white screen and stop execution
}
```

How can I achieve this, considering it's just for debugging purposes?

Comment: `exit($val);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function dumpAndDie($var)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($var); // or print_r($var);
    die;
}
```

Using the `<pre>` html tag will output a more readable result (preformatted), especially in case of objects/arrays

Comment: Exactly what I was loooking for. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

you can use the die() feature, passing in the variable as parameter.

```
die($val);
```

But if you want more details about that variable, like the type and such, you may use var_dump or print_r the same way but you will need to add exit; to kill the program.

Comment: Have you got an idea on how to get print_r well-formatted? json-like, you know.

Comment: print_r will format it nicely (human-readable) when the variable is an Array, similar to how var_dump works. 
print_r can also return the value if the second parameter is true

Comment: If your variable is an array and you really want it to print in the JSON format, you can simply do   die(json_encode($var));

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `die;` function after echo

Like this:

```
function doSomething(){
    $val = "some text";
    echo $val;
    die;
   // or use die($val);
}
```